# Какой знак нужен перед "как": тире или все-таки запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Некогда мне сейчас заниматься этой мелочью как сдам отчет, тогда займусь.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(1) Некогда мне сейчас заниматься этой мелочью — (2) как сдам отчет, (3)тогда займусь.***

Это сложное предложение с бессоюзной и союзной   связью,  оно делится **на две смысловые части**: простое предложение 1 и предложения 2 и 3, связанные местоименной подчинительной связью КАК...ТОГДА.

Между первой и второй частью отношения **причинно-следственные,** которые мы обозначаем **тире** на письме и паузой в устной речи.

А при постановке **запятой** двухчастная конструкция не будет обозначена.

Такое упрощенное оформление (с одними запятыми) мы иногда допускаем в личных записях. В этом случае обозначаются только границы между предложениями, но не смысловые отношения между ними.

Answer (score 1):

**Некогда мне сейчас заниматься этой мелочью — как сдам отчет, тогда займусь.**

[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151)

> Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире,
>   если в ней содержится следствие, результат либо вывод из того, о чем
>   говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому,
>   тогда и т. п.).